# Colorbox Prev/Back buttons not working. Exit does?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

Forgive my newbie status, I'm a UX designer who is getting more into code. I created an image gallery using two piecs of Jquery. Gridify and Colorbox. Everything is working fine except Colorbox is not showing the Prev/Next buttons. It is showing the exit button.

Here's a pastebin for the [HTML](http://pastebin.com/nVh1TLa7), and [colorbox CSS](http://pastebin.com/9WcpydJi)

A common problem is that the image folder hasn't been moved, but I did that, and I know it's working at least somewhat because the exit button is appearing.

Also I can't seem to alter the opacity for the overlay background. I've opted for getting rid of it (as you'll see in my colorbox CSS), but maybe the problem with changing the opacity is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

straight from colorbox documentation if you need to show as a gallery then use

```
    $('a.gallery').colorbox({rel:'gal'});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have been able to see that, just really new to Jquery. Thanks so much!

Comment: if you feel the answer helped you then please select it as the correct answer by clicking on the tick icon.